# Python: N Puzzle (8-Puzzle) Solver Heruistics: How to iterate?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, depth-first-search

I have written a selection of functions to try and solve a N-puzzle / 8-puzzle.

I am quite content with my ability to manipulate the puzzle but am struggling with how to iterate and find the best path. My skills are not in OOP either and so the functions are simple.

The idea is obviously to reduce the heruistic distance and place all pieces in their desired locations.

I have read up a lot of other questions regarding this topic but they're often more advanced and OOP focused.

When I try and iterate through there are no good moves. I'm not sure how to perform the A* algorithm.

```
from math import sqrt, fabs
import copy as cp

# Trial puzzle
puzzle1 = [
    [3,5,4],
    [2,1,0],
    [6,7,8]]

# This function is used minimise typing later
def starpiece(piece):
    '''Checks the input of a *arg and returns either tuple'''
    if piece == ():
        return 0
    elif isinstance(piece[0], (str, int)) == True:
        return piece[0]
    elif isinstance(piece[0], (tuple, list)) and len(piece[0]) == 2:
        return piece[0]

# This function creates the goal puzzle layout
def goal(puzzle):
    '''Input a nested list and output an goal list'''
    n = len(puzzle) * len(puzzle)
    goal = [x for x in range(1,n)]
    goal.append(0)
    nested_goal = [goal[i:i+len(puzzle)] for i in range(0, len(goal), len(puzzle))]
    return nested_goal

# This fuction gives either the coordinates (as a tuple) of a piece in the puzzle
# or the piece in the puzzle at give coordinates 
def search(puzzle, *piece):
    '''Input a puzzle and piece value and output a tuple of coordinates. 
    If no piece is selected 0 is chosen by default. If coordinates are 
    entered the piece value at those coordinates are outputed'''
    piece = starpiece(piece)
    if isinstance(piece, (tuple, list)) == True:
        return puzzle[piece[0]][piece[1]]
    for slice1, sublist in enumerate(puzzle):
        for slice2, item in enumerate(sublist):
            if puzzle[slice1][slice2] == piece:
                x, y = slice1, slice2
    return (x, y)  

# This function gives the neighbours of a piece at a given position as a list of coordinates
def neighbours(puzzle, *piece):
    '''Input a position (as a tuple) or piece and output a list 
    of adjacent neighbours. Default are the neighbours to 0'''
    length = len(puzzle) - 1
    return_list = []
    piece = starpiece(piece)
    if isinstance(piece, tuple) != True:
        piece = search(puzzle, piece)
    if (piece[0] - 1) >= 0:
        x_minus = (piece[0] - 1)
        return_list.append((x_minus, piece[1]))
    if (piece[0] + 1) <= length:
        x_plus = (piece[0] + 1)
        return_list.append((x_plus, piece[1]))
    if (piece[1] - 1) >= 0:
        y_minus = (piece[1] - 1)
        return_list.append((piece[0], y_minus))
    if (piece[1] + 1) <= length:
        y_plus = (piece[1] + 1)
        return_list.append((piece[0], y_plus))
    return return_list

# This function swaps piece values of adjacent cells 
def swap(puzzle, cell1, *cell2):
    '''Moves two cells, if adjacent a swap occurs. Default value for cell2 is 0.
    Input either a cell value or cell cooridinates''' 
    cell2 = starpiece(cell2)
    if isinstance(cell1, (str, int)) == True:
        cell1 = search(puzzle, cell1)    
    if isinstance(cell2, (str, int)) == True:
        cell2 = search(puzzle, cell2) 
    puzzleSwap = cp.deepcopy(puzzle)
    if cell1 == cell2:
        print('Warning: no swap occured as both cell values were {}'.format(search(puzzle,cell1)))
        return puzzleSwap
    elif cell1 in neighbours(puzzleSwap, cell2):
        puzzleSwap[cell1[0]][cell1[1]], puzzleSwap[cell2[0]][cell2[1]] = puzzleSwap[cell2[0]][cell2[1]], puzzleSwap[cell1[0]][cell1[1]]
        return puzzleSwap
    else:
        print('''Warning: no swap occured as cells aren't adjacent''')
        return puzzleSwap

# This function gives true if a piece is in it's correct position
def inplace(puzzle, p):
    '''Ouputs bool on whether a piece is in it's correct position'''
    if search(puzzle, p) == search(goal(puzzle), p):
        return True
    else:
        return False

# These functions give heruistic measurements 
def heruistic(puzzle):
    '''All returns heruistic (misplaced, total distance) as a tuple. Other 
    choices are: heruistic misplaced, heruistic distance or heruistic list'''
    heruistic_misplaced = 0
    heruistic_distance = 0
    heruistic_distance_total = 0
    heruistic_list = []
    for sublist in puzzle:
        for item in sublist:
            if inplace(puzzle, item) == False:
                heruistic_misplaced += 1          
    for sublist in puzzle:
        for item in sublist:
            a = search(puzzle, item)
            b = search(goal(puzzle), item)
            heruistic_distance = int(fabs(a[0] - b[0]) + fabs(a[1] - b[1]))
            heruistic_distance_total += heruistic_distance
            heruistic_list.append(heruistic_distance)

    return (heruistic_misplaced, heruistic_distance_total, heruistic_list)

def hm(puzzle):
    '''Outputs heruistic misplaced'''
    return heruistic(puzzle)[0]

def hd(puzzle):
    '''Outputs total heruistic distance'''
    return heruistic(puzzle)[1]

def hl(puzzle):
    '''Outputs heruistic list'''
    return heruistic(puzzle)[2]

def hp(puzzle, p):
    '''Outputs heruistic distance at a given location'''
    x, y = search(puzzle, p)[0], search(puzzle, p)[1]
    return heruistic(puzzle)[2][(x * len(puzzle)) + y]

# This is supposted to iterate along a route according to heruistics but doesn't work
def iterMove(puzzle):
    state = cp.deepcopy(puzzle)
    while state != goal(puzzle):
        state_hd = hd(state)
        state_hm = hm(state)
        moves = neighbours(state)
        ok_moves = []
        good_moves = []
        for move in moves:
            maybe_state = swap(state, move)
            if hd(maybe_state) < state_hd and hm(maybe_state) < state_hm:
                good_moves.append(move)
            elif hd(maybe_state) < state_hd:
                ok_moves.append(move)
            elif hm(maybe_state) < state_hm:
                ok_moves.append(move)
        if good_moves != []:
            print(state)
            state = swap(state, good_moves[0])
        elif ok_moves != []:
            print(state)
            state = swap(state, ok_moves[0])


>> iterMove(puzzle1)
'no good moves'
```

Comment: Do you have a specific error or portion of the program written that is not yielding the desired results?

Comment: It never stops running as their is no break/return in the iterMove() function. This is because there are no good moves (ie. moving the 0 doesn't lower the heruistics). Apparently you have to continue to iterate contineously towards the goal state but I do not understand how that is specifically implimented.

Answer (score 0):

To implement A* in Python you can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html for a priority queue.  You put possible positions into the queue with a priority of "cost so far + heuristic for remaining cost".  When you take them out of the queue you check a set of already seen positions.  Skip this one if you've seen the position, else add it to the set and then process.

An untested version of the critical piece of code:

```
queue = [(heuristic(starting_position), 0, starting_position, None)]
while 0 < len(queue):
    (est_moves, cur_moves, position, history) = heapq.heappop(queue)
    if position in seen:
        continue
    elif position = solved:
        return history
    else:
        seen.add(position)
        for move in possible_moves(position):
            next_position = position_after_move(position, move)
            est_moves = cur_moves + 1 + heuristic(next_position)
            heapq.heappush(queue,
                          (est_moves, cur_moves+1,
                           next_position, (move, history)))
return None
```

Comment: So I ran this with my code, the first issue is that position is referenced before assignment. Do I set position in the while loop as all possible iterations from start_position. ie ```for possible_move in neighbours(starting_position) :    position = swap(puzzle, possible_move) ```

Comment: @Jack That was a mistake.  Make it queue instead.  It is a queue of tuples and the position is a part of the tuple.

Comment: Do I have to define a set called seen?  Because it's not defined in the code. Nor is solved

Comment: @Jack Yes.  solved should be the position you are looking for.  And seen needs to be a set.  That's part of why I said "the critical piece of code" and not "working code".